# Get the first occurrence of a string in python

Tags: python, python-re

Suppose my string is: `s='[{abc:, xyz}, {something}, {and so on}]'`

I would like to get the first occurence of everything between `{` and `}`, i.e. in this case it would be `{abc:, xyz}`

This is what i tried

```
import re

s='[{abc:, xyz}, {something}, {and so on}]'

re.findall('(\{.*\})', s)[0]
```

Comment: `re.findall('(\{[a-z0-9, :]+\})', s)[0]`

Comment: Thx. Do you want to post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
re.findall('(\{[a-z0-9, :]+\})', s)[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

pattern = r'\{\w+\s*:,*\s*\w+\}'
s='[{abc:, xyz}, {abcd: 890}, {a :908}]'
res = re.findall(pattern, s)
print(res[0]) # output {abc:, xyz}
```